CUPS PDF output file name changing
Is there a way to change the CUPS PDF printer output file name? I use Ubuntu and most recent CUPS.
I tried a script, cups-pdf.conf file, lp options but I was not able to find a way.
If you have a solution for this please let me know.


Open the CUPS PDF printer configuration file in a text editor. This file is typically located at /etc/cups/cups-pdf.conf.

Look for the Out directive in the configuration file.

By default the Out directive will look like this:
Out ${HOME}/PDF


Change it by adding a custom filename template.
Out ${HOME}/PDF/%U-%s.pdf


%U -> username
%s -> print job name.


Save

Restart CUPS to apply the changes:
sudo systemctl restart cups




Thank you for your answer Tijil Saka. I did exactly what you said, but the PDF I printed this way appears empty. It deletes the currently produced PDF output and pastes only the static name. What I exactly want is to start the PDF outputs with stdntrn and add timestamp with the user login information while keeping the content of the PDF.

This is what is generated.  drwx------ 2 informix informix  4096 May  8 22:08 %U-%s.pdf
